# WorkManager from lib vs AllowBackup True from app

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm having trouble with the combination of WorkManager from my lib and AndroidManifest's allowBackup of my customer app

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<application
    android:name="._internal.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
...
```

I have some periodic workers that are scheduled using my lib project.
This lib will be implemented inside my customer app using gradle

**gradle**

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.mylib:lib:2.2.19'
}
```

**The problem is**

If my customer put *allowBackup="true"* in his app, when the user uninstall and install it all data from Workers are restored. This happens because naturally WorkManager creates a SQLite database inside the app, and this flag *allowBackup="true"* tells android to backup and restore this kind of data in this scenario.

When the user reinstall the app and open it, all periodic workers are started and this is bad for my lib. The Workers must be started only when the lib creates it.

I can't tell all the customers to set this flag to false because they could need it for some reason.

**What I expect**

DISABLE this behaviour for all the Workers that were created by my lib, without changing AndroidManifest *allowBackup* flag of host app

Comment: this may what you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles

Comment: @Library545 this solution requires the host app to change its AndroidManifest, right? I would like a solution that I need to change only the code from my lib, I can't tell the host app owner to change anything in his app

Comment: You can add it on your side, all resources (yours and the owners) will be merged when the owner build the project, but if the owner set their own backup file in the same field, it won't work. so you have to check what they exactly do with backup and write down needed change in your lib document. BTW, there is another method below the article called `BackupAgent`, you can write your own backup agent class and set it to manifest, if your owner wants to do the same thing, ask them to extend your backup agent class

Comment: you got it wrong man. your customer don't know if you've set allowBackup true or false and i would suggest to keep it false otherwise implement Backup Agent because this flag sometime creates several backup related problems. Check out this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.

Comment: @Bali but I don't want to backup anything on my lib. I just want that my customer (host app) do not have the power to backup my lib data.